# Kubuntu : display avatar in lightDM

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, settings

lightDM isn't displaying my avatar when I try to login (i changed it in kde control center)
would it work if I used gnome control center for user management ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change your avatar via your KDE settings a hidden image called `.face.icon` is stored in your `/home` folder. Unfortunately lightdm looks for an image called `.face`, which doesn't exist and that's the reason why Login screen doesn't match with user settings.

An easy workaround is to copy your `.face.icon` and rename it to `.face`

In my opinion this is, however, something that should be fixed in near future.